# Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods Angular 6 firebase

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I face a weird problem after updating versions of nodejs and npm when I'm trying to serve firebase functions **locally** (after deploy everything working perfect).

details: 
When I try to send put and/or delete request from angular6 application to fireabse which is served locally the console error is like this one:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost:5000/PROJECT-NAME/us-central1/helloWorld'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight
>   response.

But in case of post/get request everything is going fine

**Versions:**

```
NodeJS: 10.15.3
NPM : 6.4.1
firebase : 6.9.1
OS: macOS Mojave (10.14.4)
```

I'm using CORS in server;

```
    const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
    exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
        res.send({message: "Hello from Firebase!"});    
    })

});
```

and here is my package.json file

```
    {
      "name": "functions",
      "scripts": {
        "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
        "build": "tsc --skipLibCheck",
        "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
        "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
        "start": "npm run shell",
        "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
        "logs": "firebase functions:log"
      },
      "main": "lib/index.js",
      "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.18.0",
        "@sendgrid/mail": "^6.3.1",
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "core-util-is": "^1.0.2",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "fetch-base64": "^2.1.2",
        "firebase-admin": "^7.3.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
        "image-to-base64": "^2.0.1",
        "request": "^2.88.0",
        "request-promise": "^4.2.2",
        "string-similarity": "^3.0.0",
        "stripe": "^6.26.1",
        "twilio": "^3.29.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
        "tslint": "~5.8.0",
        "typescript": "^3.3.3"
      },
      "private": true,
      "engines": {
        "node": "10"
      }
    }
```

here is a screenshot of server result
[image]

Comment: any chance of answer ?

Comment: This has started happening to me as well since upgrading to firebase-tools@6.9. It might be worthwhile to try changing the `serve` command to `firebase emulators:start --only functions` *edit* - There's a github issue tracking this https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1275

Comment: Thank you Alex!, I already downgrade and now working fine for me.

Comment: It's still not working on version 6.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

the problem comes after firebase-tools update as I mentioned in the question.
versions of 6.9.0 and 6.9.1 have this problem.
Simply I downgrade to 6.8.0 and now it's working fine for me!